# How do I change the Table of Contents in Word 2010 to show only headings 1-3?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

My Word 2010 table of contents shows all headings (headings 1-6 in my particular case).

I only want the first 3 levels included, so how do I exclude headings starting with level 4?

Comment: If you are having issues, make sure your selected text is the start of the sentence (as a header 3). You cannot grab the middle of a sentence, assign it Header 3 status, and assume it shows up in a TOC.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. On the ribbon, select **References**, **Table of Contants**, **Insert Table of Contents...**
2. Under **General**, set **Show levels** to 3.
3. If you want to select other styles to be shown on the TOC, press **Options** and type the level number next to the styles you want to include.  This is useful if you have separate styles for chapter headings and apendicies.

Answer (score 46):

If the table of contents has already been created, press `Alt-F9` to display the mark up. In my case this was

> { TOC \o "1-6" \h \z \u }

Change 1-6 to 1-3, giving:

> { TOC \o "1-3" \h \z \u }

Then press `Alt-F9` again to return to the normal view and update the table as usual.

Comment: Better answer than the accepted one, IMO!

Answer (score 2):

In the Table of Contents dialog, just change the "Show levels" setting from 6 to 3. Reference here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/change-the-levels-in-a-table-of-contents-HA102322816.aspx

Comment: That link/URL is gone. Maybe this one? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/format-or-customize-a-table-of-contents-9d85eb9c-0b55-4795-8abb-a49885b3a58d