# Word 2010 -- How can you make heading 4, 5, etc.. visible in the table of contents?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, styles, table-of-contents

Word has Headings 1 - 9, but by default only 1 - 3 will show in the TOC.

So, to apply a style to selected text other than Heading 1 - 3, I have done this:

> 1. select the text
> 2. right-click the selected text
> 3. select `Styles...` from the dropdown list
> 4. select `Apply Styles...` from the dropdown list
> 5. type `Heading 4` into the textbox, and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

Now that the text is styled correctly, it does **not** show in the TOC! I have read mention of changing the "field codes" of the TOC to something like this:  `{ TOC \o "1-4" }`, but such examples only applied to Word 2007...

So how do you do this in Word 2010?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the Table of Contents in Word 2010 to show only headings 1-3?](http://superuser.com/questions/365346/how-do-i-change-the-table-of-contents-in-word-2010-to-show-only-headings-1-3)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the same method as in Word 2007.

1. Click the 3 vertical dots in the box that say "Update Table" at
   the top so the whole table is selected
2. Right click and select "Toggle Field Codes" (or type
   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>)

You should see `{TOC \o "1-3" \h\z\u}`.

3. Edit the part where it says `"1-3"` to whatever amount of indents you'd like e.g. `"1-4"` for 4 indents
4. repeat Steps 1 and 2
5. Click "Update Table...".

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @darthbith. Hmm, so when I do this, the entire selected text of the TOC is replaced with the existing field code `{TOC \o "1-3" \h\z\u}`. How do I stop it from deleting all of the TOC's text?

Comment: Nevermind, I just figured it out -- following these instructions I modify the field code to `{TOC \o "1-4" \h\z\u}` as was suggested. Then I click on the 3 vertical dots on the upper-left of the TOC *again*, right click the TOC textarea and select `Toggle Field Codes` *again* to revert it back to its' text. Then you have to update the TOC to see the change take affect.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot to mention how to change it back :-) I'll edit the answer. Glad it worked for you!

Comment: Also, see here: http://superuser.com/questions/365346/how-do-i-change-the-table-of-contents-in-word-2010-to-show-only-headings-1-3?rq=1

Comment: Nothing happends, when selecting the three dots... Alt+F9 works.

Answer (score 6):

A simpler solution would be to select the table of contents and click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. You should probably see the following code:
`{ TOC \o "1-3" \h }`

Change `3` to `4` and the problem should be solved.

Again click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to see table of content.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the REFERENCES tab, select TABLE OF CONTENTS.
2. Click Custom Table of contents
   a window with a Print Preview shows you what is currently showed.
3. below in GENERAL section, SHOW LEVELS: you can go up or down to the level you want to have visible.
4. OK and your TOC is now updated to the level you chose.

Comment: This works, and is a lot less simple and less dangerous than the other recommended methods.