# MS Word 2013 - Is it possible to not include headings 3 and 4 in the outline/table of contents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2013

I'd like to set page breaks to certain styles that apply to section headings, but I don't want those headings to appear in the outline/table of contents. There's just too many of them and it would clutter the TOC. From what I can tell, you only get to change the Page Break settings in the "Paragraph" menu, which is only in Heading styles. It's grayed out in the other styles.

So is there a way to just not include Heading 3's and Heading 4's in the outline/TOC? Any alternate solution would be great too. Thanks.

UPDATE: It was brought to my attention that this question has been asked already re: the table of contents by itself. That's half of my question for sure, but when even if you exclude Heading 4 & 5 from the table of contents, they still show up in the Navigation window on the left of the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the Table of Contents in Word 2010 to show only headings 1-3?](https://superuser.com/questions/365346/how-do-i-change-the-table-of-contents-in-word-2010-to-show-only-headings-1-3)

Comment: This does solve the table of contents problem, but those headings still show up in the Navigator. I use the Navigator a lot to jump around long reports, and it would just clutter it up to have so many sub-headings listed there. But that's still half the problem solved! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the heading text in a table and it won't show in the navigation pane. This 'feature' (bug?) has been a staple in Word for many years...

Excluding a heading from a TOC can be done by editing the TOC configuration.